# Collation for query in FluentNHibernate

Tags: sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate + LINQ, with MS SQL 2008.

What I'm trying to achieve, is accent-insensitive search, which, in SQL would look like this:

```
select * from people where name = 'somestring' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Is it possible to write something like this:

```
Session.Query<Person>.Where(p => p.Name == "somestring").WithCollation();
```

Comment: can you change the Collation in Database for this column?

Comment: perhaps my answer is what you need too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:
http://blog.schuager.com/2009/06/case-sensitive-queries-in-nhibernate.html